# Toggle input on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve something very simple but I can't figure it out. I would like to disable an input field whenever a button is clicked, then re-enable it when the button is clicked again.

I'm surely making this overly difficult (new to JS).

My current code is here in this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6pqugkg3/9/)**.

Any help is appreciated. An explanation of what I have been doing wrong would also be great as I'd like to learn :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var toggleText = $("#ip").val();
  
  $("#ipclear").click(function() {
    if ($("#ip").val() != 'N/A') {
      toggleText = $("#ip").val();
      $("#ip").val('N/A');
      $("#ip").prop("disabled", false);
    } else
      $("#ip").val(toggleText);
      $(this).toggleClass('btn-default').toggleClass('btn-warning');
      $("#ip").prop("disabled", true);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name='ip' id="ip" class='form-control' value="1.2.3.4">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ipclear">Not Applicable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing braces after `else`.

Comment: thanks @gcampbell for that, but when I add the missing braces it doesn't fix the issue. Actually it behaves differently - almost the opposite of what I want.

Comment: @johnny_s well yes, but you obviously forgot the brackets, so now you start again, with the brackets, and see what else you have to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pqugkg3/16/)**

You've to add braces `{}` arround else statement code or just first line `$("#ip").val(toggleText);` will be considered as else code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toggleText = $("#ip").val();

    $("#ipclear").click(function() {

        if ($("#ip").val() != 'N/A') {
            toggleText = $("#ip").val();

            $("#ip").val('N/A');
            $("#ip").prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
        } else{
            $("#ip").val(toggleText);
            $("#ip").prop("disabled", false);
            $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default');
        }

    });
});
```

**Note :** you have to use `addClass()/removeClass();` instead of `toogleClass()` in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome, so you have just to change the boolean inside  `$("#ip").prop("disabled", false);` to true and `false` will be in else statement, check my updated fiddle.

Comment: For the button class check please if that what you want **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6pqugkg3/16/)**.

Comment: Quick question, this works perfect however when the input is `disabled` the data doesn't post to my database. Whenever I remove the `disabled` it posts fine - any ideas?

Comment: Yes that normal @johnny_s you have to use `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled` so just replace it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#ipclear').click(function(){
            var attr = $('#ip').attr('disabled');
            if(attr == null)
            {
                $('#ip').attr('disabled', true);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#ip').attr('disabled', null);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage with ToggleClass().
On click button add one toggleclass on input and check this class condition for disabled.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var toggleText = $("#ip").val();

  $("#ipclear").click(function() {
    $("#ip").toggleClass("click");
    if ($("#ip").hasClass('click')) {
      toggleText = $("#ip").val();
      $("#ip").val('N/A');
      $("#ip").prop("disabled", false);
    } else
      $("#ip").val(toggleText);
      $(this).toggleClass('btn-default').toggleClass('btn-warning');
      $("#ip").prop("disabled", true);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , its working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var toggleText = $("#ip").val();
  
  $("#ipclear").click(function() {
  
    if ($("#ip").val() == 'N/A') {
    $("#ip").val(toggleText);
      toggleText = $("#ip").val();
      $("#ip").prop("disabled", false);
    } else{
     
        $("#ip").val('N/A');
      $(this).toggleClass('btn-default').toggleClass('btn-warning');
      $("#ip").prop("disabled", true);
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name='ip' id="ip" class='form-control' value="1.2.3.4">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ipclear">Not Applicable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```